# how to add all social share buttons in cs cart front end page

Tags: php, cs-cart

I need to display the all social share button for share my blog page in cs cart . How to do ?

```
     I have following code in meta.tpl 

     <meta property="og:title" content="ShareThis Homepage" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="Sharing Widgets" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://sharethis.com" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://sharethis.com/images/logo.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Sharing is great!" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="ShareThis" />

    In BLog page :-

    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=localhost/post/" target="_blank">
      Share on Facebook
    </a>



    Output :
             Nothing Display in facebook share link ..
     I need to share the description,image and so on.

    Please help me.How to do...
```